# Converting a formula to JavaScript for use in unity

Tags: javascript, math, formula, unityscript

I'm wondering if anyone could help me on how I would write this formula in JavaScript:

[image]

I've been searching for an answer for over an hour or so now but I'm not entirely sure how to word it correctly

the site in which the formula comes from has a calculator which shows what L2 would equal to.

the numbers I'm putting into it are:

r1 = 1
r2 = 2

L1 = 145

and the result should return as:

L2 = 138.98

[site with calculator](http://www.sengpielaudio.com/calculator-distance.htm)

Cheers

Comment: Check out `Math` in JavaScript - has everything you need. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math

Comment: What were you searching for? "javascript absolute value" and "javascript log" give me some pretty useful results.

Comment: I've tried searching a number of different keywords. I'm not exactly the best at maths so I have no idea what the | or the dot between the '20' and the 'log' is for...

Comment: @RyanGourlay maybe you should learn about the math operations behind the equation before attempting to program it. It may be prudent to at least try to gain a minimal understanding of the operations involved even if not their purpose. As a starting point, the dot denotes multiplication and the bars denote absolute value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about

```
l2=l1-Math.abs( 20 * Math.log(r2/r1) )
```

Comment: Sadly your L2 returns as: 1982.401 when it should return as: 138.98. I've updated my question to show what should be returned and what values I've used.

Comment: I just realised that you put a * instead of a - after L1. after changing it the result is now: 131.13 which is almost perfect.

Comment: You have to check what kind of logarithm is used. In decibel computations, it will most surely not be the natural logarithm, but either log10 or log2.